# How to properly place Geometry in Geometry Node

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

I am looking for a way for the cutout object to be displayed on the vertical edges of the cubes in the blend file. I achieved this for now by creating a vertex group and by moving the cutout shape manually until it is more or less at the edges of the cubes.
But I want this to happen in the Geometry Node, so it is easier to control.
I am using the current 2.92.0 Beta Version of Blender.
Glad for any ideas on this.

[image]

Comment: do you mean that you can move it like this? https://youtu.be/DTSKkG6HvFo

Answer (score 0):

if the answer to my comment is "yes"...here is the solution for geometry nodes:

just add a transform node before the boolean operator and connect the translation to your group input node. Of course, if you need rotation too you can connect them as well.

[image]